# Solana Token Swap Program - Program log: panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0', token-swap/program/src/state.rs:61:17

Tags: token, javascript, js, swap

I am facing an issue when I try to create a token swap through the js binding for the token swap program.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token-swap

I don't get the error meaning and then I don't know how to debug  it. are you able to give me any advice or help ?

Full logs:

```
Program log: Instruction: Transfer
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4644 of 600000 compute units
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]
Program log: Instruction: Transfer
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4644 of 595356 compute units
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success
Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw invoke [1]
Program log: Instruction: Init
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]
Program log: Instruction: MintTo
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4492 of 578031 compute units
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success
Program log: panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0', token-swap/program/src/state.rs:61:17
Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw consumed 20125 of 590712 compute units
Program failed to complete: BPF program panicked
Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw failed: Program failed to complete
```

My code:

```
export async function addLiquidityNewPool(
  connection: Connection,
  publicKey: PublicKey,
  sendTransaction: any,
  tokenAMint: string,
  tokenBMint: string
) {

  const TokenAPubkey = new PublicKey(tokenAMint);
  const TokenBPubkey = new PublicKey(tokenBMint);

  const transaction = new Transaction();

  console.log("creating pool account");
  const tokenSwapStateAccount = Keypair.generate();
  const rent = Swap.TokenSwap.getMinBalanceRentForExemptTokenSwap(connection);
  const tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction = await SystemProgram.createAccount({
    newAccountPubkey: tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey,
    fromPubkey: publicKey,
    lamports: rent,
    space: Swap.TokenSwapLayout.span,
    programId: Swap.TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
  });

  transaction.add(tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction);

  //Find authority for the PDA
  const [swapAuthority, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey.toBuffer()],
    Swap.TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  //Token A Account Creation
  let tokenAAccountAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    TokenAPubkey, // mint
    swapAuthority, // owner
    true // allow owner off curve
  );
  const tokenAAccountInstruction =
    await createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      publicKey, // payer
      tokenAAccountAddress, // ata
      swapAuthority, // owner
      TokenAPubkey // mint
    );

  transaction.add(tokenAAccountInstruction);

  //Token B Account Creation
  let tokenBAccountAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    TokenBPubkey, // mint
    swapAuthority, // owner
    true // allow owner off curve
  );
  const tokenBAccountInstruction =
    await createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      publicKey, // payer
      tokenBAccountAddress, // ata
      swapAuthority, // owner
      TokenBPubkey // mint
    );

  transaction.add(tokenBAccountInstruction);

  // Create a LP Token mint
  const mint = await Keypair.generate();
  const LPCreateTokenMintInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
    space: MINT_SIZE,
    lamports: await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection),
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  });
  const LPInitTokenInstruction =
    // init mint account
    createInitializeMintInstruction(
      mint.publicKey, // mint pubkey
      2, // decimals
      swapAuthority, // mint authority
      null // freeze authority (you can use `null` to disable it. when you disable it, you can't turn it on again)
    );

  transaction.add(LPCreateTokenMintInstruction);
  transaction.add(LPInitTokenInstruction);

  //Pool Token Account : account that the initial liquidity pool tokens get minted to when the swap account is first created.
  const tokenAccountPool = Keypair.generate();
  const rent2 = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptAccount(connection);
  const createTokenAccountPoolInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: tokenAccountPool.publicKey,
    space: ACCOUNT_SIZE,
    lamports: rent2,
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  });
  const initializeTokenAccountPoolInstruction =
    createInitializeAccountInstruction(
      tokenAccountPool.publicKey,
      mint.publicKey,
      publicKey
    );

  transaction.add(createTokenAccountPoolInstruction);
  transaction.add(initializeTokenAccountPoolInstruction);

  //Pool Token Fee Account

  const feeOwner = new PublicKey(
    "HfoTxFR1Tm6kGmWgYWD6J7YHVy1UwqSULUGVLXkJqaKN"
  );

  let tokenFeeAccountAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mint.publicKey, // mint
    feeOwner, // owner
    true // allow owner off curve
  );

  const tokenFeeAccountInstruction =
    await createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      publicKey, // payer
      tokenFeeAccountAddress, // ata
      feeOwner, // owner
      mint.publicKey // mint
    );

  transaction.add(tokenFeeAccountInstruction);

  const {
    context: { slot: minContextSlot },
    value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight },
  } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

  const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
    skipPreflight: true,
    minContextSlot,
    signers: [mint, tokenSwapStateAccount, tokenAccountPool],
  });
  console.log(signature);

  await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature,
  });

  //Add liquidity in a second Tx and init the swap. This is to prevent fund loss.

  const TokenAUserAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    TokenAPubkey,
    publicKey
  );
  const TokenBUserAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    TokenBPubkey,
    publicKey
  );

  const TransferAInstructions = await createTransferInstruction(
    TokenAUserAccount,
    tokenAAccountAddress,
    publicKey,
    1000000
  );
  const TransferBInstructions = await createTransferInstruction(
    TokenBUserAccount,
    tokenBAccountAddress,
    publicKey,
    1000000
  );

  const createSwapInstruction = Swap.TokenSwap.createInitSwapInstruction(
    tokenSwapStateAccount, // Token swap state account
    swapAuthority, // Swap pool authority
    tokenAAccountAddress, // Token A token account
    tokenBAccountAddress, // Token B token account
    mint.publicKey, // Swap pool token mint
    tokenFeeAccountAddress, // Token fee account
    tokenAccountPool.publicKey, // Swap pool token account
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Program ID
    Swap.TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Swap Program ID
    0, // Trade fee numerator
    10000, // Trade fee denominator
    5, // Owner trade fee numerator
    10000, // Owner trade fee denominator
    0, // Owner withdraw fee numerator
    0, // Owner withdraw fee denominator
    20, // Host fee numerator
    100, // Host fee denominator
    Swap.CurveType.ConstantProduct // Curve type
  );

  const Tx = new Transaction().add(
    TransferAInstructions,
    TransferBInstructions,
    createSwapInstruction
  );

  const signature2 = await sendTransaction(Tx, connection, {
    skipPreflight: true,
  });
  console.log(signature2);

  await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. Finally I succeeded to figure it out. The issue was coming from the fact that the token swap account creation should occur in the same transaction as the new Token Swap initialization.

It means that the `tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction` and `createSwapInstruction` should be send in the same transaction.

https://spl.solana.com/token-swap

> Note that the pool state account is not required to be a signer on initialize, so it's important to perform the initialize instruction in the same transaction as its system_instruction::create_account.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error tripped up is from this line: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/token-swap-v3.0.0/token-swap/program/src/state.rs#LL61C4-L61C4

You're trying to write to an uninitialized buffer, so it seems like the first transaction hasn't landed when you're doing the second transaction. Be sure to configure your state commitments on your `Connection` to all be `Confirmed` to be sure that everything is running at the right state.

Or you can even do a check in between the two transactions to make sure that the token swap state account is properly assigned to the token swap program and allocated with enough bytes.

Because otherwise, it looks like you're doing everything correctly.

More information at https://docs.solana.com/api/http#configuring-state-commitment